# card io integrated with paypal sdk is not working

Tags: android, paypal

I have integrated Paypal Sdk in my android app.It is having two options to pay using Paypal user account and to pay using credit card.Payment with credit can be done by card Io library but don't know why it is not working.Not working means  it is not scanning card.Please tell me  how to use it .I just keep card in front of long time but it does not fetch the details from the card .

SDK version 2.0.2

**Logcat while scanning card**

```
03-14 11:05:20.000: E/mm-camera(140): Ignoring execution of AEC as AF is active
03-14 11:05:20.060: E/mm-camera(140): Ignoring execution of AEC as AF is active
03-14 11:05:20.110: E/mm-camera(140): Ignoring execution of AEC as AF is active
03-14 11:05:20.110: W/QCameraHWI_Preview(132): android::status_t android::QCameraStream_preview::processPreviewFrameWithDisplay(mm_camera_ch_data_buf_t*): dis_proc_time 0ms, asd_proc_time 0ms, gpu_proc_time 0ms, face_proc_time 3ms, genlock_unlock_time 0ms, genlock_lock_time 0ms, enqueue_time 3ms, dequeue_time 0ms, ion_flush_time 2ms, lock_buffer_time 0ms, buf_done_time 8ms, data_callback_time 27ms, frame_proc_time 46ms
```

Even not able to made transaction by filling card details .App is getting crash

**Logcat after filling card details :**

```
03-14 11:09:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(25350): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-14 11:09:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(25350):    at com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService.h(Unknown Source)
03-14 11:09:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(25350):    at com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentMethodActivity.a(Unknown Source)
03-14 11:09:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(25350):    at com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentMethodActivity.f(Unknown Source)
03-14 11:09:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(25350):    at com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.aj.onServiceConnected(Unknown Source)
03-14 11:09:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(25350):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1187)
03-14 11:09:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(25350):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1204)
03-14 11:09:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(25350):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-14 11:09:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(25350):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-14 11:09:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(25350):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
03-14 11:09:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(25350):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5520)
03-14 11:09:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(25350):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 11:09:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(25350):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-14 11:09:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(25350):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
03-14 11:09:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(25350):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
03-14 11:09:23.370: E/AndroidRuntime(25350):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-14 11:09:23.380: E/EmbeddedLogger(343): App crashed! Process: com.paypal.example.paypalandroidsdkexample
03-14 11:09:23.380: E/EmbeddedLogger(343): App crashed! Package: com.paypal.example.paypalandroidsdkexample v1 (1.0)
03-14 11:09:23.380: E/EmbeddedLogger(343): Application Label: PayPal SDK Example
03-14 11:09:26.480: E/ThermalDaemon(25739): Thermal daemon started
```

Comment: Can you please provide more information?  Info such as the sdk version you're using, relevant logs related to your problem, and screenshots to help describe your problem.  Thanks!

Comment: @JeffBrateman please look through .I have updated question .

Comment: Did you start PayPalService before launching the intent?  Or, did you stop the service?  Both of those could have caused the error you're seeing.